# JAVA - Writing sentences to textfile

Tags: java, string, bufferedreader, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I have this code below. Basically I'm getting an input from a given url. This website shows a sentence. Each time I reload the website it gets a new sentence and so on. So, I managed to get that working. Now I'm trying to write the sentence in a textfile. But something is wrong. It only writes the first line and nothing else. What's wrong with my code?

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;

public class ReadIp {
public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, IOException,     
InterruptedException {
    ReadIp readIP = new ReadIp();
    while (true) {
        readIP.getIP();
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}

BufferedReader      buff;
InputStreamReader   inStream;
String              line;
URL                 url;
URLConnection       urlConn;
FileWriter fileWriter ;
BufferedWriter bufferedWriter;

public ReadIp() throws IOException {
    fileWriter = new FileWriter("myfile.txt", true);
    bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);
}

public void getIP() throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
    this.url = new URL("http://test.myrywebsite.co.uk");
    this.urlConn = this.url.openConnection();
    this.inStream = new InputStreamReader(this.urlConn.getInputStream());
    this.buff = new BufferedReader(this.inStream);

    try {
        while ((this.line = this.buff.readLine()) != null) 
        {
            System.out.println(this.line);
            try {
                this.bufferedWriter.write(this.line);
                this.bufferedWriter.write("\n");

                this.bufferedWriter.flush();

            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
            } 

        }
        if (this.bufferedWriter != null) 
        {
            this.bufferedWriter.close();
        }

       this.inStream.close();

    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
    }


}
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: I dunno, maybe it has something to do with you closing the writer after you've written the first line?

Comment: Don't use empty catch blocks. You're getting multiple exceptions and ignoring them.

Answer (score 5):

Move the statement

```
writer.close();
```

out of the inner try catch block so that you're not closing the `OutputStream` after writing the first entry to the file. The same applys to the `InputStream`

```
inStream.close();
```

Comment: As @TheLostMind pointed out, he not only closes the writer (preventing further writes), but also closing the input stream after the first line read. That should also be moved out of the while loop.

Comment: @Orodous:Input stream should not be problem.As evertime when  readIP.getIP(); is called.It will create a InputStream object. inStream = new InputStreamReader( urlConn.getInputStream()) will do it everytime.Right?

Comment: @AbhijeetPanwar - he closes it after he reads *one line*. So, the next line will not be read.

Comment: @Ordous so I edited the code and took out inStream.close and writer.close from the while loop. It's still giving me only the first sentence

Comment: When you say "took out" you mean move to a location _after_ the `while` loop - right? I.e. don't remove just move the statements. Also remember when you use `writer.write` everything will appear on one line. You could use [`println`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#println(java.lang.String))

Comment: @Reimeus yes I moved the statements to a location after the while loop as you can see in the updated code above. But I'm still getting first sentence only.

Comment: That's because you're truncating the file when using the default constructor for `FileWriter` as well as not flushing `BufferedWriter`

Comment: @Reimeus okay I edited the above code again. Did like you said. I'm still not getting the right thing. It's still giving me first sentence and that's it.

Comment: Since you're using an infinite loop don't close the bufferedWriter. I would use a sentinel value in the loop rather then loop forever so that you can do a final tidy up of resources

Answer (score 0):

The BufferedWriter is being opened in the constructor and is being closed in `getIp`. The constructor is called only once, but `getIp` is called every 2 seconds to read a sentence. So the BufferedWriter is being closed after the first line (and not opened again). The second call of `getIp` tries to write the second sentence but the BufferedWriter is closed. This should throw an Exception which is being ignored since the catch block is empty.

**Never leave a catch block empty** - as **fgb** wrote above!

First of all, at least add a `printStackTrace()` to *each* empty catch block, e.g.:

```
    catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

so you can see if an Exception is being thrown...

I would suggest to open the `BufferedWriter` in the method `getIp` instead of the constructor; or, if it should stay open all the time, close the `BufferedWriter` in an additional method, called after the loop in `main` terminates